# Redirect Function Php

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have a function, 'redirect_to()' written on php script that is called after a successful update to a page on my custom CMS. It works fine on the localhost, but when I try it on my actual live domain I get the following error message:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb/web119/b1192/ipg.typaldosnetcom/edit_listing.php:7) in /hermes/bosweb/web119/b1192/ipg.typaldosnetcom/includes/functions.php on line 20

Here is the code for the redirect_to() function:

```
function redirect_to ($location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

I've made sure to call the function before I output any HTML, so I'm not sure what the problem really is.

My question: **Why am I receiving this error?**

Comment: Perhaps there is a space character before some `<?php` tag? What does  /hermes/bosweb/web119/b1192/ipg.typaldosnetcom/edit_listing.php:7 contain?

Comment: What's on line 7 of edit_listing.php?

Comment: It was a whitespace issue...a hidden space. Thanks all.

Comment: Another common cause of this error is by encoding your _source file_ in UTF-8 with a byte order mark.  If you encode your file as UTF-8, do so without a BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already sent your output to the page before you set the header. first you need to set the headers and then can the output come.

It can even be a whitespace.

Comment: UTF-8 BOM can also make a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not lying. You've output something before getting to this point. Check the locations mentioned in the error messages.

Show us the first 25 lines of each of the files mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It means something was already outputted on the suggested line. Try going there and see what it does.

Try pasting the surrounding code on that position for a better clarification if you can't find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One common cause is to have a line after a php file you're including...

Simple solution: remove the closing php tag "?>" from all files as it's not needed..

Answer (score 0):

Use output buffering:

```
<?php 
ob_start();

// Test buffered output. 
echo 'hello world'; 

function redirect_to ($location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header('Location: ' . $location);
        exit;
    }
}

// rest of php file here

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Docs: [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/ob-start)  and [ob_end_flush()](https://www.php.net/ob-end-flush)

Comment: How would this help? Buffering a function definition does nothing at all - the error would only show up when the function's called and the function's execution would NOT be buffered.

Comment: Assuming the output is happening on the same file, this will work. See the `// rest of php file here`? So quick to downvote, tsk tsk.

Comment: Also, I'm not suggesting he buffer the function, lol. Think about it homie.

Comment: I agree with @AlienWebguy.  If output is buffered, then nothing will be sent until the buffer is flushed.  This would solve the problem of extraneous output being sent to the client before the header function is reached, if that is the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if you have a character before the opening php-script tag by removing any closing php-script tag. This way you are sure there isn't any character left (it's not needed).